# Spring MVC, tomcat url 404 error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have problem with spring-mvc/tomcat, and more specifically with Url
When I'm trying to execute: http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/index.html

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/index.html]   in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'

HelloWeb-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.solsoft.web"/>

<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/pages"/>
        </bean>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

StudentController:

```
@Controller
public class StudentController{
private static List<User> userList=new ArrayList<User>();
static {
    userList.add(new User("Bill", "Gates"));
    userList.add(new User("Kasia", "K"));
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index (@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("userList", userList);
    return "index";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
    if (null != user && null != user.getName()
            && null != user.getLastName() && !user.getName().isEmpty()
            && !user.getLastName().isEmpty()) {
        synchronized (userList) {
            userList.add(user);
        }
    }
    return "redirect:index.html";
}
}
```

web.xml:

```
<display-name>HW</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Thank U for all tips

Answer (score 0):

What if you add .html to your RequestMappings e.g. @RequestMapping(value="/index.html")

Comment: What is the name of the file that gets created/deployed. Is it HelloWeb.war

Comment: Yes. If you do not explicitly give a context name as per your server (I mainly deal with weblogic and need to assign context name within weblogic.xml) then it picks up the name of your file and it is case sensitive.

Comment: I'm deploying HelloWeb.war file and get same answer from server. thanks for your commitment

Comment: I do not see <mvc:annotation-driven/> in your servlet config. Can you add and check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml, you've mapped the DispatcherServlet to handle requests matching *.html. But your StudentController is not mapped to handle such requests.

Modify the value in @RequestMapping to include .html extension.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index (@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model){
   ......
   return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
   .....
   return "redirect:index.html";
}
```

Now try to access your page by going to http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/index.html

-----------Edit-----------------------------

Verify the Controller is getting initialized by Spring. To do that, create a no-arg constructor and try to print something to the console.

```
@Controller
public class StudentController{

       public StudentController(){
              System.out.println("Hey, I'm in StudentController");
       }

}
```

Comment: @Tommy that's interesting. Can you try something? Create a no args constructor in your Controller. Just write one SysOut statement inside the constructor. Then restart your app. Verify if the sysout appears in your console. If it doesn't, then your Controller isn't getting recognized by Spring container. If the SysOut shows up in the console, then there is some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`
in your servlet config. Can you add and check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to deploy your HTML files as simple static files, you should configure them as such.  Add this to your dispatcher servlet, making sure you have the proper namespace declared:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="*.html" location="/" />
```

You don't need a controller method to serve this file.  If you want additional logic on the back-end, you can have your request to `/index` do its thing and then redirect to your file, or just convert `index.html` to a .jsp file.  Right now, your controller is most likely trying to find a JSP view named `index.html`, which does not exist.